# How to find out which line threw an exception in scala repl?

Tags: scala

I have a piece of code that I run in scala repl.
The code throws an exception.
How to find out which line does that?
There are line numbers in the stacktrace, but they are wrong.
In the example below the stacktrace says that the exception was thrown at line 13, but the code has only 5 lines.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

if (math.random > 0.5) {
  throw new Exception()
} else {
  throw new Exception()
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

java.lang.Exception
  ... 28 elided

scala> lastException.printStackTrace
java.lang.Exception
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:13)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:742)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had better luck with [Ammonite REPL](https://ammonite.io/)

```scala
@ {
    if (math.random > 0.5) {
      throw new Exception()
    } else {
      println("here")
      throw new Exception()
    }
  }
java.lang.Exception
  ammonite.$sess.cmd2$.<init>(cmd2.sc:2)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd2$.<clinit>(cmd2.sc)


@

@ {
    if (math.random > 0.5) {
      throw new Exception()
    } else {
      println("here")
      throw new Exception()
    }
  }
here
java.lang.Exception
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$.<init>(cmd3.sc:5)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$.<clinit>(cmd3.sc)
```

Counting the `if` statement as line 1 then lines 2 and 5 seem correct here as places where the exception can be thrown.